# Change Netatalk server name

Tags: networking, file-sharing

Is there a way to change the name of a Netatalk AFP server, as shown by the client?

I run Netatalk3 on FreeBSD 10.1 with OS X clients. On the clients I see the server labeled with its hostname. I would change that to something more descriptive.

Netatalk is supported by AHVHI in FreeBSD default configuration.

Answer (score 2):

Set the hostname parameter in the Global section of `afp.conf`

e.g. `/etc/netatalk/afp.confg`

```
[Global] 
; Global server settings
hostname = my-afp-server-name
```

On older Netatalk 2 installations this file is called `afpd.conf`

Comment: Under Raspian, this file seems to be "/etc/netatalk/afpd.conf" rather than the paths specified in this answer.

Comment: (It looks like this is a netatalk v2 vs. v3 difference…)

Answer (score 0):

For the netatalk 2.2 version that's still part of Raspbian (why-oh-why is every Linux distro so out of date on so much stuff??) I had to use the following:

```
vi /etc/netatalk/afpd.conf

      # add line at end of file
      "Your Machine"

service netatalk restart
```

This looks funny, but basically says "configure a server named Your Machine with the default options".

Note that the netatalk daemon is primarily an AFP server. Your machine may also use the Avahi daemon to advertise itself over mDNS, in which case you may also want to change the host name there:

```
sudo vi /etc/avahi/avahi-daemon.conf

    host-name=Your Machine

service avahi-daemon restart
```